# Detecting Runs and Groups in a Horizontal Grid of Cards in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am working on a Python project where I have a dictionary representing a 10x21 grid of cards. Each card in the grid is either a dictionary containing information (if present) or None if the position is empty.

I need help implementing a Python script to detect and print runs and groups horizontally in this grid. The criteria for runs and groups are as follows:

Runs:

A run consists of three or more consecutive cards with the same color.
The values of the cards in the run must form a consecutive sequence of even or odd numbers.

Groups:

A group consists of three or more consecutive cards with the same value.
The colors of the cards in the group must be different.
I've provided an example grid below, where x is the dictionary representing the grid:

```
x = {0: None, 1: None, 2:{'color': 'blue', 'value': 3}: 3:{'color': 'blue', 'value': 4}, 4:{ 'color': 'blue', 'value': 5} ...  208: None, 209: None}
```

I would appreciate any assistance or guidance on how to implement the logic for detecting and printing runs and groups horizontally in this grid. Any sample code or explanations would be highly beneficial.

Thank you for your help!

I am not sure how to write program for this.

Comment: Have you thought of using Pandas? The Dictionary could be converted directly into a DataFrame and then the data would be 1. clearer to visualize 2. easier to write the code to detect runs and groups.

Comment: what did you try? where is your code? Maybe first try something and come back when you get error message.

Comment: you can use `for`-loop to get all cards with the same value and later you can use `!=` to check if they have different colors. And it may need another `for`-loop to do this for every value: `for val in range(1, 13): for k,v in data.items(): if card and card['value'] == v: ...`. A similar way you can use `for`-loops to get all cards with the same color, sort them by value and later check `val1 == val2 - 1 == val3 -2` or check average `(val1 + val2 + val3)/3 == val2`

Comment: you may also use `itertool.groupby()` to group by color (and check if they have different colors - i.e. `len(group) == len(set(group_colors))`. Or group by value and later check `val1 == val2 - 1 == val3 -2`. You may also use `pandas` to keep as `table` (`dataframe`) and use `dataframe.groupby('color')`